# How can I find the x,y and z of a point w.r.to the camera coordinates in a stereo pair, given the K matrices of both the cameras?

Tags: camera-calibration

I have two calibrated cameras C1 and C2 and assuming that their optic axes are perfectly parallel and the baseline is known, can someone please explain how I can calculate the x,y and z of a point from the pixel coordinates from C1 and C2 for the same point?